# android MediaPlayer IO Exception with E(-1003,-403)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, media-player, http-status-code-403, ioexception

I got an url to play video from nimble server with wmsAuth key that is concatenated.
When wmsAuth key is fine the video plays well.
The logic I am trying to implement is, right after the media-player throws (-1003,-403) on what and extra, I need to refresh wmsAuth key.it worked fine on some devices. But the problem I faced was some devices throw IO exception only not being specific on (-1003,-403).
As IO exception carry various exception not being specific to (-1003,-403) the logic cannot be implemented on catch block of IO exception.
How can we go to depth of IO exception to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this exception in following way:

1. Add this line to your Application's onCreate() function

   ```
   CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager())
   ```
2. Use [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) for playing your resource